# jquery slider not working on masterpage asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

          $("div#banner_content").jContent({ orientation: 'vertical',
            easing: "easeOutCirc",
            duration: 500,
            auto: true,
            pause_on_hover: true,
            direction: 'next'
        });

    });
```

It works fine on another page not using a masterpage

```
  <div id="banner_content">
            <big runat="server" id="slides1"></big>
        </div>
```

I am adding my content from c# backend

When i debug in firebug i get this error in the Error console where as i have no such element on my MasterPage

[image]

**NOTE:** All my scripts are working fine as i have tested the code on another page

Comment: Please check the reference for dependent files for plugin

Comment: do you have `runat="server"` in you banner_content div?

Comment: yes i do have runat= "server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described, there may be 2 problems. The CSS error looks like it is probably coming from an authentication issue and is being redirected to a login page. Just from what I can make out form the screen capture you have put in.

The other error, it may be cause from the fact the id of the element you are trying to access is being created server side. So you could do something like the following in your javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $("div#<%=banner_content.ClientID%>").jContent({ orientation: 'vertical',
        easing: "easeOutCirc",
        duration: 500,
        auto: true,
        pause_on_hover: true,
        direction: 'next'
    });

});
```

or you can use Static IDs by defining the ClientIDMode in either your master page, page, or individual controls:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem of id which changes as you use master page. So if you are using asp.net 4.0 you can use

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

as follow

```
 <div id="banner_content" ClientIDMode="Static" >
        <big runat="server" id="slides1"></big>
    </div>
```

or in your jquery code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("div#<%= banner_content.ClientID %>").jContent({ orientation: 'vertical',
        easing: "easeOutCirc",
        duration: 500,
        auto: true,
        pause_on_hover: true,
        direction: 'next'
    });

});
```